# What role is the い playing in "している"?

Tags: conjugations

The sentence

> トニーはいい声をしている。

apparently translates to

> Tony's voice is nice.

**Question:** The verb "している", according to jpdb.io, is the て continuous conjugation of する. But when I look up the て continuous conjugation elsewhere, I see it written as "してる" (without the い).  So what is the い doing here in "している"?

Comment: The form is ている and the い is sometimes in speech - I also feel this could have been combined with your other question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

してる is a colloquial spelling/pronunciation of している. The continuous forms of verbs are created by taking the ―て form and adding your desired conjugation of いる.
In casual spoken Japanese the い is sometimes dropped in the continuous form of verbs because it's easier to pronounce. The い is not "playing a role," rather it is being dropped in very casual speech.